# how to make a logical OR of an area memory pointed by an array

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, logical-operators

supposing to have two arrays a[N],b[N] containing only 0 and 1 values, is there a way to calculate c = a || b without a loop like the following (in C)?

```
#define N 10
char a[N];
char b[N];
char c[N];


// suppose to do some operations on a and b so that 
// for each i a[i] == 0 or a[i] == 1
// and the same for b

// this is the loop i would want to avoid
int i;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     c[i] = a[i] || b[i];
```

I would want to calculate the result of (a || b) directly comparing the two memory areas, but i don't know if it's possible.
thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: btw: bitwise or is a single pipe |

Comment: a[i] | b[i]  is very different from a[i] || b[i].  | is bitwise.  || is logical

Comment: sorry, i'm wrong: i meant logical or. i edited the question.

Comment: If you can assume x86 architecture for this then SSE would be the way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since bitwise or is an operation that has to be applied to a single value, I don't think there is. Is there a particular reason you want to avoid the loop? If it's a hassle, making a function out of it is easy.

**Edit:** The question has now changed to logical OR, but I don't think the answer is much different.

Comment: well the reason is this is needed for an algorithm implementation but it typically results in thousands of repetitions of that loop. My intent is to increase the performances of the algorithm's implementation.

Comment: Since I don't think it can be made as one big OR in the hardware, there would definitely need to be some kind of loop. One optimization might be to OR the elements in bigger chunks, casting the chars together into 8-char (64-bit) integers, and then OR-ing those. Not sure if that'll improve performance though. Also, is performance an issue, or is it just a theoretical improvement you're looking for?

Comment: i've to process video sequences. i need to compare two pixel neighborhood which can (now) be arrays of 4 or 8 elements. They could be extended to 15 elements.

Comment: Sound like you are trying to create a kind of jpeg encoder here.

Comment: no, i'm trying to obtain an accurate value of the perimeter of a blob and some other shape descriptors

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#define c(index)    (a(index) || b(index))
```

This gives you a symbolic c-array. Just remove the c variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You could typecast the character array to the largest integer that your machine supports, and then do the OR operation on the integers which would save you some instruction cycles. Note that you will have to choose your array size in multiples of the size of the integer you are using.

```
    #define LARGE_INTEGER unsigned long long

    #define ACTUAL_SIZE 10

    #define SIZEOF_LARGE_INT sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER)

    #define N (ACTUAL_SIZE + (SIZEOF_LARGE_INT - (ACTUAL_SIZE % SIZEOF_LARGE_INT)))

char a[N] = {0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1};
char b[N] = {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0};
char c[N];

LARGE_INTEGER *pa, *pb, *pc;

int i;

for(i = 0; i < N; i = i + SIZEOF_LARGE_INT)
{
    pa = (LARGE_INTEGER*) &a[i];
    pb = (LARGE_INTEGER*) &b[i];
    pc = (LARGE_INTEGER*) &c[i];

    *pc = (*pa) | (*pb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

premature optmization.  put this in a profiler before spending any more time.  The compiler might do stuff like unroll the loop or work on chunks at a time on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for x86 then you can process 16 array elements at a time using SSE:

```
// NB: we're assuming:
//   - N is a multiple of 16
//   - a[], b[], and c[] are 16 byte aligned

for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 16)
{
    __m128i va = _mm_load_si128(&a[i]);
    __m128i vb = _mm_load_si128(&b[i]);
    __m128i vc;
#ifdef LOGICAL_OR // NB: only need these two lines if we are doing logical OR - omit for bitwise OR
    va = _mm_add_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(va, _mm_set1_epi8(0)), _mm_set1_epi8(1));
    vb = _mm_add_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(vb, _mm_set1_epi8(0)), _mm_set1_epi8(1));
#endif
    vc = _mm_or_si128(va, vb);
    _mm_store_si128(vc, &c[i]);
}
```

Comment: @ralu: it should be up to 16x faster than naive scalar code, but it's possible that memory bandwidth may be the limiting factor and so you may see somewhat less than this, depending on the CPU, FSB speed, memory latency/bandwidth, etc

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you'd *want* to do so, but you could also turn the iteration into tail recursion:

```
int do_or(int n, int *a, int *b, int *c) { 
    if (0 == n)
       return;

    *c = *a || * b;
    do_or(n-1, a+1, b+1, c+1);
}
```

Probably a better alternative would be to encode the 0's and 1's as actual bits in an unsigned number, in which case you can use a bitwise `or` to do the job in a single operation:

```
unsigned long a, b, c;

// code to set/clear bits in a and b elided

c = a | b;
```

You're guaranteed that an `unsigned long` can hold at least 32 bits, and an `unsigned long long` can hold at least 64.